# Problem calling a Local HTML File from XCode

Tags: objective-c, file, uiwebview, local

Here's my WebView Code:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Here's my Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
```

Can anyone help? It's saying nil string but the NSURL string is index.html

My only thought is that perhaps the index file isn't stored correctly. It's in the project directory - the same folder as the XCode project file xcodeproj and the info.plist

Comment: there is not space between `fileURLWithPath:` and `isDirectory:`

Comment: that makes no difference. I copy/pasted above code from a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the file is copied to your application bundle. When `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:]` returns nil very most likely there is no file with this name in the bundle

In Xcode3 right click the "Groups & Files" header in the side bar and select "target membership". Make sure the checkbox in front of index.html is checked.

Comment: It was unchecked. Thanks man. If I have the file in web/index.html how do I do this? It's not accepting `pathForResource:@"web/index" ofType:@"html"] `

Answer (score 1):

URLs have to define how to obtain information, not just what the file is called. This means you have to specify the full URL, like http://www.something.com/index.html or file:///Users/Daniel/Sites/index.html.  What you are specifying is a *URI* not a *URL*

For the difference between a URL and URI: http://www.damnhandy.com/2007/11/19/uri-vs-url-whats-the-difference/

Apple docs for NSURL: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: and `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` creates a URL out of a path.