# Why does UIWebView local file bring up an NSException error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem calling a Local HTML File from XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380572/problem-calling-a-local-html-file-from-xcode)

I am using the following code with my already existing UIWebView to call a local file into the UIWebView:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iDHSB_iPod/Calendar" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

However, when the button is pressed to carry out this function - I get this error:

```
2011-11-27 20:17:37.667 iDHSB[806:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** 
-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x37c598bf 0x3173f1e5 0x37c597b9 0x37c597db 0x31b014ff 0x31b01493 0x4b609 0x37bb3435 0x3502c9eb 0x3502c9a7 0x3502c985 
0x3502c6f5 0x3502d02d 0x3502b50f 0x3502af01 0x350114ed 0x35010d2d 0x3772edf3 0x37c2d553 0x37c2d4f5 0x37c2c343 0x37baf4dd 
0x37baf3a5 0x3772dfcd 0x3503f743 0x2e8b 0x28d4)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the error, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iDHSB_iPod/Calendar" ofType:@"html"]` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use local path as argument for the `pathForResource:ofType` method; it accepts only resource name.